# How to use .keyword with ElasticaAdapter and omines/datatables-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, datatables

please how to refer to field.keyword when using Omines/Datatable and  ElasticaAdapter.

When I use the code below, it throws me an error. Paid month contains data like 6/2023

```php
 $table = $this->createDataTable() 
            ->add("mois_paye.keyword", TextColumn::class)
            ->createAdapter(ElasticaAdapter::class, [
                'client' => ['host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => 9200], 
            ])
            ->handleRequest($request);
```

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSp7t.png)

I need to use keyword (mois_paye.keyword) to make search available on attribute.

Thank you